# Pass Object Key As Generic

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to pass each key in an object as a generic to each corresponding value in that object? For instance:

```js
interface Items
{
    [key: Key extends string]: Item <Key>;
};

interface Item <Key>
{
    name: Key;
};
```

This can be achieved if the keys are a string literal:

```js
type Name = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type Items =
{
    [Key in Name]?: Item<Key>;
};

interface Item <Name>
{
    name: Name;
};

const items: Items =
{
    // Type valid
    a:
    {
        name: 'a'
    },
    // Type error
    b:
    {
        name: 'c'
    }
};
```

I'm not sure how this can be extended to allow any string. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a generic type that computes the value type from the key type:

```
interface Item<Key> {
    name: Key;
};
```

Given a collection, which is your `Name` of the types of the keys, you can compute the overall object type. So why not make `Name` generic?

```
type Items<Name extends string> = {
    [Key in Name]?: Item<Key>;
};
```

Now you want to validate if a given type, which is the type of your object literal, fits into the `Items` constraint. That is, whether there exists a type `Name`, such that the type of the object literal is exactly `Items`. There is no direct formation of existential type in TypeScript, but this can be done with inference from function parameters:

```
function checkType<Name extends string>(items: Items<Name>): Items<Name> {
    return items;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
const items = checkType({
    a: {
        name: 'a',
    },
    b: {
        name: 'c', // cannot pass the check
        // name: 'b', // passes the check
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting solution. It's unfortunate, though, that it requires the use of a function. If there's no alternative, that may have to be accepted, but it would be preferable to avoid that.