# Extract an object's properties and their generic types within a function's type annotation

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Question

How can I extract an object's properties and their generic types within a function's type annotation?

I need to be able to infer the type `RequestData`, so that type propagates properly to the `request` callback.

Currently when invoking this function, I have to write my `request` callback with type assertions. I would like my IDE to infer the type of `data` based on the `Form` object being passed in.

Also, any advice on how to get rid of the `any` in my example is appreciated.

Thanks!

## Example

```js
class Field<T> {
  value: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Form {
  // Object containing all Field objects in this Form
  fields: Record<string, Field<any>>;

  constructor({ fields }: { fields: Record<string, Field<any>>; ) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }
}



const submit = async <Response extends unknown, RequestData extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  form: Form,
  request: (data: RequestData) => Promise<Response>,
): Promise<Response> => {
  const fieldsAsGenerics = {} as RequestData; // Extract value stored in every form.field

  return await request(fieldsAsGenerics);
};



const myForm = new Form({
   fields: {
    name: new Field<string>('Charlie'),
    age: new Field<number | null>(66),
  }
});

submit(myForm, async (data) => {
  // data should be of type { [K in keyof typeof myForm.fields]: typeof myForm.fields[K] }
  // which in this case is { name: string; age: number | null }
  // Actual type is unknown
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Ei9lQ0jjCAlxoWUYBFHQ1IVD8SBfi4ro+wHOgCTHN0wA3Oh90PY8zwvKIzETRBk1TdNM2gECwFUATEFUEBgVCJRoBwAAGcsn0IIA)

## See also

- [TypeScript: how to extract the generic parameter from a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851268/typescript-how-to-extract-the-generic-parameter-from-a-type)
- [Pass Object Key As Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672087/pass-object-key-as-generic)

Comment: For Typescript questions, you might want to consider linking to a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). It becomes a lot faster for answerers to run your code :)

Comment: Thanks @Mack! I just added the playground link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this issue is that your `Form` type is not generic, so the compiler does not know any information about the types of fields that are present. One `Form` object cannot be distinguished at compile time from any other `Form`, so they can't have different behaviour based on the types of fields they hold.

So, let's make `Form` generic on the type of the field-containing `Record` that it contains.

```
class Form<T extends Record<string, Field<any>>> {
  // Object containing all Field objects in this Form
  fields: T

  constructor({ fields }: { fields: T}) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }
}
```

Now, we use a utility type to extract the RequestData type out of the above record type (effectively, removing the Field wrapper).

```
type ExtractFieldValues<T extends Record<string, Field<any>>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Field<infer V> ? V : never;
};
```

We can tweak the `submit` function to work with the new types, with one caveat. There will always need to be a type assertion when you're unboxing the values from instances of `Field`. The compiler isn't alert enough to analyse any loops you may use to do so and guarantee that every property of the `Fields` type has been included:

```
const submit = async <Response extends unknown, Fields extends Record<string, Field<any>>>(
  form: Form<Fields>,
  request: (data: ExtractFieldValues<Fields>) => Promise<Response>,
): Promise<Response> => {
  const fieldsAsGenerics = {
      // Extract value stored in every form.field
  } as ExtractFieldValues<Fields>;
  // A type assertion will ALWAYS be required here:
  // the compiler can't infer that you're looping over every
  // property of the form type and extracting T from Field<T>.
  
  return await request(fieldsAsGenerics);
};
```

To avoid the type assertion, it may be wise to store the values directly in the `fields` object without the `Field` wrapper, but this might not be possible or useful depending on the rest of your code.

The types can now be inferred correctly in usage (mouseover in the playground link to confirm):

```
const myForm = new Form({
 fields: {
    name: new Field<string>(/*Field constructor argsargs*/),
    age: new Field<number | null>(/*Field constructor args*/)
  }
});

submit(myForm, async (data) => {
  // data should be of type { [K in keyof typeof myForm.fields]: typeof myForm.fields[K] }
  // which in this case is { name: string; age: number | null }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWBTEATAPAFQHzQN4FgAoaaAelOgGUAXAewCdEYxoA3MEAV0WloDNo1AJ4AHHhiIBfIkVCQYsBgFtM0RAA9qiAHYoYAJUTAG6CNXrxtAcwA0cJKjRhtQrG7xES5aAHkARgBWRtTQxtrUYJaWVtAcIPbIKLyBwTCWggAW8ArKntB8DnoAXNAShHlhZvScwHT0ABS4+YUwkiVNBYkQJRiSAJQexCSZ2QB0nagwALzNXQDcedKES8Ji0ACimvRgtQiJAGoc3BCqGlq6BkYmaFXRdnuOzq7uMwRDJADaANLQ6QDWiCE-FKAF0et8QWpNDo9AlHJY+Ih6NB9jgAPwo6AlbSIVhIhbLAmyWjaMzQCCcPxKeAhGaQITaYDQNCGCAiEkQHhnGEwTjaP7aWgAd209xaUPOsMMxnopnMdzh6Cebiw9TyfGUJUU9BUDz0WBseUYAEdjtQSvUUGAIiVNuYdtQ9YcuEw0HqIFgBlMcAAFei0amcllMdmkxAGoh9Ep+gPZRDBtkc8PQb2DEiVEITPQAQQgAHEdEj4MBpmnhl4KHbtrU2EceGYGIgkulcUihPllONCotYjAqw6nXWTu6sASK9Bs4JRDx5EjqPASdAhfAQPFswAZADq2YAmpRoH4eCbOPBGEkMkjEEU8t5qBfQgGRCukaFnAByEIIl9363QIGcN9GGgEBaFoJ9rF4PFkVbeghBvCgRH9MR6GEXgBDvHgNR1Kc1mcJIzmrecIIwfJ-SUFE60wLBRjyI1EGoTh6G0WIhUiEJjyYah6izCBcwLHELBLPoCUkIlynEjNoCUIRtXImYcSFOBlEaTwePaPISG0MAlCvaAFMVG55WsVVSAAKj1B9SXMGo6liegrAgMB7IgUzSD6Q13liKxdP0vU0G0TglEPZEAB89M4VcTPMwpLKqGyGDshzXL6RYpGEmRCApKkaXqaTZLselGWgS1rTAL0cDect4OgK0InJDJaAipJDzQnCeCab5fmYgEgXQ6dgTyzseLBNqBpkoaWghaAlnHIUsmADIupGGBgEgHhsjwPTtN025rDmLyfMC4LoDCgLV2mtK5iAA)

Comment: You're a lifesaver :D This works perfectly. You are correct that I cannot remove the Field wrapper in my situation, because that class holds a lot more than just the value.

Comment: I don't mind keeping the type assertion `as ExtractFieldValues<Fields>;`. That is far less frustrating than having to assert the type of each property on the `data` object.